# IronPython in PyCharm 3rd Party DLLs

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, pycharm

I have IronPython right now working with PyCharm. Is it possible to import classes from a 3rd party .NET DLL that I have written and get code completion with it?

Currently I'm creating a .NET application where users can upload their Python scripts and interact with the application. Basically I want to create a .NET library that users can import into their Python project and use classes from it with code completion.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyCharm handles Python C extensions by generating a "skeleton" module and using that for completion. The same approach would work for IronPython easily, thanks to .NET reflection, but I don't know if PyCharm supports that sort of extensibility.

Comment: It does, strangely enough. However, it seems to only really work on the core libraries (e.g.: System.Data.dll, System.dll, etc). Other than that, not really. In older versions (3.0.2 and prior), it would throw an Exception trying to generate the file. Now, in 3.1, it simply ignores the request if it fails.